# list view has thumbnails but i cant change the colour of the text?

Tags: html, css

i am a complete newbie and have been trying to get my head around it all. I have a list view with thumbnails, i cant manage to change the text colour next to the thumbnail.
I also tired having a grid view with a img and text in the centre but to no joy. 
I know both of these will be simple to you guys , i would love and appreciate some help please. :)

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="listview-1">
  <li>
    <a href="item1.html">
      <img src="eatright.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb" />
      Nutrition
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="item2.html">
      <img src="calories.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb" />
      Calories
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="item3.html">
      <img src="Gym Cat.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb" />
      Training
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="item4.html">
      <img src="supplements.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb" />
      Supplements
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<canvas width="" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: hi, i had tried style="color:green"> but that did not work. Cleary only works on paragraphs or h1-6 right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS rule

```
#listview-1 li a {
  color: red;
}
```

Sample snippet - external style

```css
#listview-1 li a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul data-role="listview" id="listview-1">
  <li>
    <a href="item1.html">
      <img src="eatright.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb" />
      Nutrition
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Sample snippet - inline style

```html
<ul data-role="listview" id="listview-1">
  <li>
    <a href="item1.html" style="color:green">
      <img src="eatright.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb" />
      Nutrition
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi buddy , you are more than likely right i think i have just place it wrong. i am not sure when i also have the image and the #ref there.

Comment: <ul data-role="listview" id="listview-1">
          <li>
              #listview li a {
              color: green;
              }
               href="item1.html">
           <img src="eatright.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb"/>
            
           </a>
          </li>
          
         </ul>

Comment: i just changed the text colour with this - <ul data-role="listview" id="listview-1">
          <li>
              <a href="item1.html">
           <img src="eatright.png" class="ui-li-has-thumb"/>
           <h2 style="color:green">Nutrition</h2> 
           </a>   does it matter if i get flags for having h2 there??

Comment: @CraigOwen I updated my answer to show 2 ways with existing markup